# Swift's ".sort" works on Simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an odd problem where some code I have written works fine on the iPhone Simulator but not working correctly on the phone itself.

Basically I am performing a sort on an array of objects. The sort is to be performed on a member of type NSString.

Here is my class definition:

```
class Event: NSObject {

    var act: NSString!
    var start: NSDate!
    var end: NSDate!
}
```

here is definition of a class I use to wrap a collection of the Event objects.

```
class Events: NSObject {
    var events = [Event]()

    func add(event: Event){
        events.append(event)
  }
}
```

I need to sort the array so I get in alphabetic order of the act. Here is how I am doing that:

```
var result = allEvents.values.array as [Event]
sort(&result){$0.act < $1.act as String}
```

The problem is: this works perfectly in the simulator but when run on the iPhone the result array is in the order of initial insertion.

I have also tried:

```
result.sort({$0.act < $1.act as String})
```

But I get the same unsorted result.

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  in events and call it when you want to sort the array
If this does't work than make act an String! instead of NSString!

***Swift 1.2***

```
 func sortEvents()
{   events.sort(){
        return $0.act.localizedStandardCompare($1.act) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending              }
}
```

***Swift 2.0***

```
 func sortEvents()
{   events.sortInPlace(){
          return $0.act.localizedStandardCompare($1.act) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending              }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. I will give those a go and report back when I have a positive result.

Comment: Your sortEvents() function is working in the simulator. I won't have access to a phone until later today, so I will report back when I test this.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back.

The sortEvents() approach did not work on the phone.

I changed the act to `String!` and still it **does not work** on the phone.

Comment: @PabloSofthead I think the problem is with your phone,try with another iOS device

Comment: The problem is that I only have access to my partner's phone now and again. It is a managed enterprise device and the only way I can get to test my apps on it is through TestFlight. But I have seen the same problem on other iPhones also after the last time I had a version published through the App Store. It really is not a great way to debug but for everything else I am trying, the simulator works same as the phone ... :-(